# How to get a list from XMLHttpRequest response in JS(from server side c#)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a site with rooms of chating... when I have a new room i try to get the list of them but I don't know how to do this...

I have a function in c# Service that insert info to properties that add to List and I return to the client... The List is a Type of "Result" Class and every line contain a 2 properties of Room Class that I have in Result too...

In my client side I need to get the List and implement it in new var property.
I get the content from server side in XMLHttpRequest and the property name that contain the content is "response"

when I write of example to see what I get:

```
var rooms = response;
alert(response);
```

If I have a 2 rooms that created for example I get a code like  this:

```
<ArrayOfResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlScheme-.....>
<Result>
<roomName>nameofroom1</roomName>
<roomToken>123456</roomToken>
</Result>
<Result>
<roomName>nameofroom2</roomName>
<roomToken>246801</roomToken>
</Result>
</ArrayOfResult>
```

the "response" is the property that I get in the "success" option of $.ajax:
like:

```
$ajax('functionInServer',{data:data,success:function(response){
var rooms = response;
alert(response);
}});
```

How can I get the list and implement it to new var for using it?
no matter what I do I get undefind or null...
(after I will do "for" or "each" to get every line of the list)...

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to parse the XML with jQuery?

Comment: something like this... I used code like jQuary that someone created but its not matter I can do it with regular jquary too

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the XML and iterate over the elements:

```
var $xml = $.parseXML(response);
var $rooms = $xml.find('result');
```